# Code always showing same output (Problem with If statements in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I tried making a tool that calculates battle out comes but this part of the code always displays: "DRAW!"

```
function battle()
{
    var rawpower = document.getElementById('rawpower').value;
    var rawpoweropp = document.getElementById('rawpoweropp').value;

    if(rawpower > rawpoweropp){
        alert("You won!");
    } else if(rawpower < rawpoweropp){
        alert("You lose!");
    } else{
        alert("Draw!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what are the values of the two variables?

Comment: you should console.log your rawpower and rawpoweropp variables to check your working with correct data

Comment: `console.log(rawpower, rawpoweropp)`

Comment: here you can check the source yourself: https://lordscalculator.neocities.org/

Comment: Or you can check it!

Comment: but i mean like you can assign your own value to both

Comment: The element with id "rawpower" is a `<p>` tag, and `<p>` elements do not have a "value" property.

Comment: @dxwϟ — You should provide a [mcve] *in the question itself*

Comment: can you post the html code , is it a input type of string or number? also what values you enter on the input fields

Comment: .value by default returns a string value and comparing string with < > compares this length of the string i think, have you tried to convert to int?

Comment: you probably want to run `parseInt` (eg `parseInt(document.getElementById('rawpoweropp').value)` on your values otherwise you are just comparing 2 strings

Comment: They are always `undefined` because rawpower and rawpoweropp are two `<p> ` nodes. To retrieve their "values", you must read the innetText property instead of value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element with id="rawpower" is a paragraph tag `<p>`. These elements do not have values. So `document.getElementById('rawpower').value` returns undefined, and same for the other line. undefined is not less than undefined, nor is it greater than undefined, so you're going into the third case.

Comment: How do you know it are paragraphs? There is no HTML code.

Comment: They eventually linked a page in the comments.

Comment: Just to mention that the right way for op to get the score from `<p>` tag is `document.getElementById('rawpower').innerHTML`.